# How to change href value using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<img class="pull-left" onclick="MarkPopup()" style="width:50px;height:50px" src="/assets/mark.jpg">
<ul class="nav pull-right">
<li>
<li>
<a href="/ContactClub">Contact Club</a>
</li>
<li>
<li class="dropdown">
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to change the href value "/ContactClub" to "somethingelse". How is this done please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways ;)

**jQuery style:**

```
// Select a with href attribute = /ContactClub
$('a[href="/ContactClub"]').prop('href', 'newhref...');
```

**Pure-js solution** (untested)

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
 if (element[i].href === '/ContactClub') {
   if (element.setAttribute !== 'function') {
     element[i].href = 'newhref';
   } else {
     element[i].setAttribute('href', 'newhref');
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: `setAttribute` should not take precedence. Actually, it shouldn't be used at all in this case. Always set the property directly if it exists.

Answer (score 3):

I would add an `id` to the `a` tag:

```
<a id="contact_link" href="/ContactClub">Contact Club</a>
```

And then do either,

```
$('#contact_link').attr('href', 'new url');
```

or,

```
document.getElementById('contact_link').href = 'new url';
```

Note: You can also use the jQuery `prop` method in the same fashion as `attr` above. This is somewhat a matter of preference. As `href` is principally thought of as an attribute (with a corresponding, but not dynamic or disconnected js property), I would suggest using `attr`. Other attributes like `value` will depend on what you're trying to retrieve. Do a bit of research on the differences.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) or [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('a[href="/ContactClub"]').attr('href', 'New Href here');
```

or:

```
$('a[href="/ContactClub"]').prop('href', 'New Href here');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E6N7s/)**

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("li a").attr("href","new value");
```